# What is the best way to handle nested conditionals in ruby?

Tags: ruby, idioms

I have the following logic:

```
if something
  some_variable = true if another_variable
  your_variable = true if that_other_variable
elsif thatthing
  my_variable = true if another_variable
  her_variable = true if that_other variable
else
  puts "nothing found"
end
```

This is extremely simplified logic. Please forgive in advance for the names of the vars.

Coming from another language, I have conditioned my mind to think that nested inline if conditions are bad for readability reasons. I also have biases towards truthiness type tests. I tried to avoid negation if possible, but some times its unavoidable.

That being said, I have a couple of common possibilities of what I could use to replace the inline ifs, and one that is more uncommon that I put together to avoid negation. I am looking for feedback, and some things that you are doing to address this. Here it goes:

Possibility 1:

ternary:

```
if something
  some_variable = defined?(another_variable) ? true : false
```

Possibility 2:

negation:

```
if something
  some_variable = !defined?(another_variable)
# There are some variations to this, but this helps to address the negation I am trying to avoid.
```

Possibility 3 (I am favoring this one, but it seems a little uncommon):

```
if something
  some_variable = (defined?(another_variable) && another_variable.length > 0)    # Two truth based tests (does the var exist, and is it greater than 0 in length) This returns true/false.
```

Please let me know if anyone has any other solutions, and also which they feel is the most idiomatic.

Thank you!

Comment: It will be much better to put a concrete code example. So that we can help. Because, generally, this kind of logic is born from bed code design.

Comment: You are right on the money. I am refactoring a script, and I am trying to beautify short of a complete rewrite. :-(

Comment: I think ``defined?`` doesn't work as you think it works. Have a look at the docs.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, what your intention is. All of your alternatives work somewhat differently, they are not all equivalent. And all of them have more concise alternatives too. It depends on what you actually mean to do, which is not clear. In general, I don't think there's any reason to prefer the ternary operator (`? :`) over a one-line if -- unless you actually find the ternary operator more readable in a given situation. The one-line if is idiomatic, if it's actually doing what you want. I think even the version you start with may not be doing what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, instead of trying to stuff my answers in comments, I'll just give an answer, even though it's not quite an "answer".

All of your alternatives are not equivalent, they all do different things. What are you actually trying to do?

```
 some_variable = true if another_variable
```

Will set `some_variable = true` only if `another_variable` has a truthy value. In ruby, any value but `nil` or `false` is evaluated as true in a boolean test. `another_variable` has to already exist, otherwise you'll get an exception raised.

- So if `another_variable` exists, and is anything but `nil` or `false`, you'll set `some_variable` to true.
- If `another_variable` exists and is `nil` or `false`, you won't change the value of `some_variable` *at all*, it will remain unchanged. It will *not* be set to false.  (if `some_variable` didn't already exist, it *will* be brought into existence with a `nil` value. Otherwise it's previous value will be unchanged).
- If `another_variable` didn't exist at all, the statement will raise an exception.

Is that what you intend?  (And incidentally, using these meaningless variable names makes it a lot more confusing to talk about your example).

If that's really what you intend (and I'm doubting that it is), then there's probably no shorter or clearer way to do it than the way you've done: `some_variable = true if another_variable`.

There's nothing un-idiomatic with a one-line trailing `if` in ruby, it's perfectly idiomatic, people do it all the time, when it makes the code more clear.  In your example -- and again it's hard to tell from your fake example -- I don't think it's the one-line if that makes it hard to tell what's going on, it is the weird structure of the top-level conditions, the overall structure of the code itself, it's very difficult to tell what the heck it's supposed to be doing.  But you say you don't want to refactor that, so okay. And maybe that's just an artifact of you trying to produce a simple hypothetical and coming up with an awfully confusing one, maybe the original code isn't as confusing.

Your other alternative examples do *something else*, they are not equivalent. For instance:

```
some_variable = defined?(another_variable) ? true : false
```

This has different semantics than your first example.

- if `another_variable` *exists at all*, then `some_variable` will be set to true. Even if `another_variable` exists with the value `nil` or `false`. So long as `another_variable` exists, `some_variable` will be set to true.
- If `another_variable` does not exist at all `some_variable` will be set to false.
- There is no case where `some_variable` will be untouched.

If *that's* really what you intend to do, then there certainly is a more concise alternative.  `defined?` returns nil if the variable is not defined, otherwise a string explaining the nature of the defined variable. If you want to turn that into strictly boolean `true` or `false`, you can use a double boolean negation:  `some_variable = !! defined?(another_variable)`. Recall that in ruby anything but `false` or `nil` is evaluated as truthy in a boolean context, so `!! foo` will turn into `false` if `foo` was `nil` or `false`, and `true` if `foo` was anything else.

People also just commonly do `some_variable = defined?(another_variable)` and figure that's good enough to capture "did `another_variable` exist", since `some_variable` will still be evaluated the same in a boolean test. Although really, in idiomatic ruby you only occasionally need `defined?` at all, mostly you are working with variables you already know exist, and you don't need to test to see if they do, and even more seldom do you need to store the results of that test in a variable.

Your additional examples all have yet different semantics again, none of them are actually equivalent. Hopefully I've given you the tools here to see what they all actually do. You can also try them all out in a little test script, or in the irb REPL.

I suspect *neither of these* are what you actually want to do. It depends on the actual semantics you want, which you haven't told us.  If your first version you start out with actually does represent the semantics you want, then I think there's no shorter way to do it.

You say you are refactoring existing code -- Based on this example you give us, I think the existing code may likely be a mess, with lots of bugs in it, written strangely, and with lack of certainty about what it's even *supposed* to do, since you aren't the original developer. I'm guessing it doesn't have any tests either. In this situation, I'd start by writing some tests establishing what the code is *supposed* to do, and then you can try refactoring and make sure it still performs as expected. Without that, and with such messy code, and especially with being newish to ruby, your refactoring is highly likely to change the semantics of the program when you weren't intending to, likely introducing new and even stranger bugs.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. This is a great perspective. So my main goal here is just to make the code more readable. The issue I have is have multiple layers of nested ifs using both block based on inlines. This stinks of code smell to me. I use inline ifs as well, however I start to get apprehensive once things start to get to nested. My biggest fear is that a conditional may be missed, and it may be hard to keep track of things due to too many decisions being made in a few lines of code. Here is another example:

Comment: if this && that && value && value
      if created_today
        some_var = that if another_var

I am seeing code like this, so it is making me cringe to some extent.

Comment: Please add newlines before every if statement above. Looks like indentation doesn't indicate code blocks in comments.. :-(

Comment: there are no newlines in comments on SO. Yeah, all your code examples are making me cringe too. But if you change the semantics of it, you are going to introduce bugs. Your alternative examples do not do the same thing as the original. If you want to clean it up, you are going to have to refactor it more substantially, not line-by-line.

Comment: Agreed. I think the real solution here is I need to do some redesign.  There is this perpetual issue of time that is always at odds with me. :) So to sum up, main goal was to increase readability. See if I could replace some of the inline variable checks to reduce the nesting depth, and make an attempt to replace those inline tests with something that had some similarities with the original test and was considered acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `true if <var>` part and can use `!!`instead:

```
if something
  some_variable = !!another_variable
  your_variable = !!that_other_variable
elsif thatthing
  my_variable  = !!another_variable
  her_variable = !!that_other variable
else
  puts "nothing found"
end
```